# SWI Prolog. Чтение из файла.

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Data - path :)

```
load(Data) :- write('Loading'), see(Data), readQuests, seen.
readQuests :- repeat, read(Quest), Quest \= end_of_file, assert(Quest).
```

почему-то зацикливается, хотя Quest \= end_of_file fail регистрирует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По [определению](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=repeat/0), `repeat` всегда срабатывает успешно, т.е. для выхода из цикла необходимо добавить `fail` или любой другой тест выдающий значение `false`, *если надо продолжать* и `true`, *если надо остановиться*. Таким образом Пролог будет вынужден вернуться назад (см. [Поиск с возвратом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)), `repeat` снова сработает и тело цикла будет выполнено ещё раз. Такие циклы по-английски называются *failure-driven loops*.

Пример из документации:

```
  repeat,
    read(Term),
    (  Term == end_of_file
    -> !
    ;  process(Term),
       fail
    ).
```

В вашем случае

```
readQuests :- repeat, read(Quest), assert(Quest), Quest = end_of_file, !.
```